# Reduction formula for $\int \cos^n(x) dx$. Why this way and not any other way?

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

I feel so overwhelmed!
for (cos(x))^n, everywhere I see the same thing:
[image]

But there are so many other possible routes, how on earth did they just know what do!?
Could have said:
$(cosx)^n=(cosx)^{n-2}(1-sinx^2)$
or $(cosx)^{n-3}(1-sinx^2)(cosx)$
andevery possible route has different branching routes! I feel so frustrated!

Comment: Don't you have enough with a route... that works ???

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to decompose $\cos^n(x)$ as you say.

However it must be borne in mind that it's the subsequent *integral* of the resulting functions that needs to be computed. The chosen decomposition ideally leads to convenient further integration by parts generating further powers of $\cos$ alone i.e. $I_n$

If you chose e.g. $\cos^n(x)=\cos^{n-2}(x)(1-\sin^2(x))$ then you'd be left with 
$$
I_{n-2}-\int \cos^{n-2}(x)\sin^2(x)\,dx
$$
The second integral cannot now be done with the trig. substitution $\sin^2=1-\cos^2$ as that just takes you back to your starting point, so you need another way of doing it, and that may or may not be obvious to you:
$$
\int \cos^{n-2}(x)\sin^2(x)\,dx =\int \cos^{n-2}(x)\sin(x)\sin(x)\,dx
$$
This can be integrated by parts by setting
$dv=\cos^{n-2}(x)\sin(x)$ and $u=\sin(x)$
giving 
$$
-\sin(x)\frac{1}{n-1}\cos^{n-1}(x)+\frac{1}{n-1}\int\cos^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)\,dx
$$
and the last integral is $I_n$ again.

So, it *is* possible to do it other ways. I feel this second way though is *less* convenient and less direct than the way you described. I think other decompositions will also be less convenient though it may be a moot point what is more convenient or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can re write as -

$$(\cos x)^n=(\cos x)^{(n-2)}(1-\sin^2x)$$

or $$(\cos x)^{(n-3)}(1-\sin^2x)(\cos x)$$

But then at some stage you need to change $$\sin^2x$$ into $$\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$ That leads to you more complex solution.

Answer (score 1):

**A different way**:

$$2^n\cos^n x=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nke^{ikx}e^{-i(n-k)x}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nke^{i(2k-n)x}\\
=\sum_{k=(n+1)/2}^n\binom nk\cos((2k-n)x)$$

by grouping the terms of opposite exponents (for odd $n$; the case of even $n$ is very similar).

Then the antiderivative is

$$\sum_{k=(n+1)/2}^n\binom nk\frac{\sin((2k-n)x)}{2n-k}+C.$$

Comment: The denominator must be $2k-n$, mustn't it?