# $I_n = \int_0^x \frac{1}{(1+r^2)^n} dr \implies I_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2n} \{\frac{x}{1+x^2}+(2n-1)I_n\}$.

Tags: integration, recurrence-relations

We define $\displaystyle I_n = \int_0^x \frac{1}{(1+r^2)^n} dr$.
Then how can we show that
$$ I_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2n} \left\{\frac{x}{1+x^2}+(2n-1)I_n\right\}$$

I have tried integration by substitution $r^2+1=t$ but it did not work well.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Answer is incorrect

Comment: Substitute $r = \tan y$ then we have recursion integral trigonometry cosine function, I hope you must be familiar with it. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211883/reduction-formula-for-int-cosnx-dx-why-this-way-and-not-any-other-way) can be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I_n=\int_0^x\frac {(1+r^2)dr}{(1+r^2)^{n+1}}$$

$$I_n=\underbrace{\int_0^x\frac {dr}{(1+r^2)^{n+1}}}_{I_{n+1}}+{\int_0^x\frac {r^2dr}{(1+r^2)^{n+1}}}$$

$$I_n-I_{n+1}={\int_0^x\frac {r^2dr}{(1+r^2)^{n+1}}}={\int_0^x r\biggl(\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^{n+1}}\biggl)dr}$$
taking,

$$\frac{dv}{dr}=\frac r{(1+r^2)^{n+1}} $$
and $$u=r$$
then $$ v=\frac{(1+r^2)^{-n}}{-2n} $$
since $$ \frac d{dr}\left(\frac{(1+r^2)^{-n}}{-2n}\right)=\frac r{(1+r^2)^n} $$
and $$\frac{du}{dr}=1$$

using intergration by parts formula,
$$I_n-I_{n+1}=\frac {-x}{{2n(1+x^2)^n}}+\underbrace{\int_0^x\frac {dr}{2n{(1+r^2)^{n}}}}_\frac{I_n}{2n}$$

Thus

$$ I_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2n} \left[\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}+(2n-1)I_n\right]$$

Comment: now I edited check

Answer (score 1):

See $I_n$ as a function of the variable $x$. It is differentiable and for all $n$, $$I_n'(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$$ In particular, you have
$$2nI'_{n+1}(x) - (2n-1)I'_n(x) = \frac{2n}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}} - \frac{2n-1}{(1+x^2)^{n}}$$ $$ = \frac{2n-(2n-1)(1+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}} = \frac{-2nx^2+x^2+1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$$

which is a primitive of
$$\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}$$

Therefore
$$2nI_{n+1}(x) - (2n-1)I_n(x) = \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}$$

i.e.

$$I_{n+1}(x) = \frac{1}{2n} \left(\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n} + (2n-1)I_n(x)\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

Note

$$\frac d{dr}\left(\frac r{(1+r^2)^n}\right) =\frac {2n}{(1+r^2)^n} -
\frac{2n-1}{(1+r^2)^{n+1} }
$$

Then, integrate both sides

$$\int_0^x\frac {dr}{(1+r^2)^{n+1}}= \frac1{2n}\frac r{(1+r^2)^n}\bigg|_0^x+\frac{2n-1}{2n} \int_0^x\frac {dr}{(1+r^2)^{n}}
$$

Thus

$$ I_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2n} \left[\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}+(2n-1)I_n\right]$$